# readonly object for unit testing is being disposed when using 'using'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, dispose, using

I have an object that is used a bunch of times within the same unit test, and in other unit tests within the same class, that is defined as follows:

```
private readonly Task<HttpResponseMessage> successfulResponse = Task.FromResult(
            new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(@"{""EntitySets"":[{""ResultSets"":[{""Results"":[{""Type"":""Message""}],""Total"":2}],""EntityType"":""Message""}]}")
            });
```

Then in each of my relevant unit tests, I'm doing something like this:

```
mockHttpClient.Setup(m => m.SendAsync(It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(v =>
            v.RequestUri.Host.Equals("example.com")),
            It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(successfulResponse);
```

... where `mockHttpClient` is a mocked `HttpClient`.

But when I'm unit testing, this sort of logic is executed in a lot of places inside the code being tested:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await this.client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken))
{
//...
}
```

... where `this.client` is `mockHttpClient` from above. As you can tell, `Moq` provides my pre-prepared `successfulResponse` object here to simulate a http response.

Problem is, when the *very first* execution of such a `using` statement is executed, it disposes `successfulResponse` when it gets out of the `using` block, and all following `using` blocks fail with the following exception:

```
Test method TestProbe_Success threw exception: 
    System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.
```

So my question is, how can I prevent the code being tested from disposing this object, which is used multiple times within the same unit test and in other unit tests ?

Comment: You're wanting to change the behavior of the method being tested, because of testing? That doesn't make sense. Let it continue to dispose it, and just provide a new instance of the HttpResponseMessage each time.

Comment: If you use a factory pattern to retrieve clients in your code, then you could mock the factory in your unit tests to return a mock client (depends on your architecture). Then in your mock client you could override the dispose to not do anything.

Comment: I want to use the `using` method because in reality when an actual response is received, it will be a different http response instance everytime .. This problem is only when I'm unit testing using the same response object

Comment: Your question is unclear. The reason for the behavior is obvious. What you want to do about it is not. If you want to keep reusing the same object, why are you disposing it (i.e. why use `using`)? Alternatively, if you want an object to be immune to disposal, why don't you implement your own version of the response class for testing purposes, which ignores calls to `Dispose()`? What is it you want _us_ to do about this problem in your code?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using a shared resource in your tests, that, if disposed by one test, will cause unwanted effects in another.

Change it to a function

```
private readonly Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> successfulResponse = () => Task.FromResult(
        new HttpResponseMessage() {
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(@"{""EntitySets"":[{""ResultSets"":[{""Results"":[{""Type"":""Message""}],""Total"":2}],""EntityType"":""Message""}]}")
        });
```

and have the setup use the delegate in its Returns

```
mockHttpClient
    .Setup(m => m.SendAsync(It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(v => 
            v.RequestUri.Host.Equals("example.com")
        ),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    )
    .Returns(() => successfulResponse());
```

That way each time a response is returned, a new instance is used.